# TLS certificate to SQLAlchemy connection

Tags: postgresql, ssl, sqlalchemy

I'm using Postgres as database, SQLAlchemy for connection. I want to introduce TLS certificate into connection. How to do it correctly and debug?
The code below allows me to commuticate with db:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = f"postgresql://{user}:{password}@{postgres_server}/{db}"
ssl_args = {'sslrootcert': {
    'cert': r'path-to-cert.pem',
    'key': r'path-to-key.pem',
                            }}

engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, echo=True, echo_pool="debug", connect_args=ssl_args)
```

but I'm sure whether it is what I need or need.
If I use the following usr (with additional parameter **sslmode=require** in the end):

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = f"postgresql://{user}:{password}@{postgres_server}/{db}?sslmode=require"
```

the communication with db fails with the error: `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: server does not support SSL, but SSL was required`

Comment: As the error message suggests, this is a problem with the server, not your code. Has the server been compiled with SSL support?

Comment: Yes, you're right, [this video explaination](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ww_1Pqi1k20) helped me to introduce SSL support. Now connection via `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = f"postgresql://{user}:{password}@{postgres_server}/{db}?sslmode=require"
` works. But now another question, why does it work even if I do not provide `ssl_args`. Should it work like this? I expected that connection fails if client does not provide `cert` and `key`

Comment: `sslmode=require` encrypts the connection, but doesn't necessarily need a certificate - see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/libpq-connect.html